# How to create index in postgresql for regexp_matches?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have a table **product**

```
product_id | desciption                                     
============================================================
322919     | text {add}185{/add} text                       
322920     | text {add}184{/add} text {add}185{/add} text   
322921     | text {add}185{/add} text {add}187{/add} text
```

sql query with **like** is very slow

```
SELECT product_id, desciption 
FROM product 
WHERE LOWER(desciption) like '%{add}185{/add}%'
> Time: 340,159s
```

I only need an index to search for {add}185{/add} expressions.
i.e. need to make an index for this table

```
SELECT product_id, regexp_matches (desciption, '(\{add\}\d+\{\/add\})', 'g') 
FROM product
```

returns:

```
product_id | regexp_matches 
================================================================================
322919     | {"{add}185{/add}"}
322920     | {"{add}184{/add}"}
322920     | {"{add}185{/add}"}
322921     | {"{add}185{/add}"}
322921     | {"{add}187{/add}"}
```

1. Which is better to create an index for data sampling?
2. Which is better to use the expression in "WHERE"?

Comment: You should look into full text indexes or GIN indexes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest solution is just to build a [pg_trgm index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html).

```
 create extension pg_trgm;
 create index on product using gin (description gin_trgm_ops);
```

Then you can use the same query, only remove the LOWER and change the LIKE to ILIKE.

That should probably be good enough, but if it isn't you can make a more targeted index. You will need to create a helper function to do an aggregation, as you can't put an aggregate directly into a functional index.

```
create function extract_tokens(text) returns text[] immutable language sql as $$ 
   select array_agg(regexp_matches[1]) from 
      regexp_matches ($1, '\{add\}(\d+)\{\/add\}+','g') 
$$;
```

Note that I moved the capturing parenthesis in, so they only get the digits and not the surrounding tags, which just seem like noise.  The fact that there was a match is evidence they were there, we don't need to see them.

```
create index on product using gin (extract_tokens(description))

select * from product where extract_tokens(description) @> ARRAY['185'];
```

Comment: Perfectly > Time: 0,253s

Answer (score 0):

For better searching you need to create index for column 'description'

When using like, remember only this wildcard work with index

```
SELECT product_id, desciption FROM product WHERE LOWER(desciption) like '{add}185{/add}%'
```

So your query above not work with index